# What is the purpose of the View Model Locator?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I'm confused with what View model locator is used for in MVVM Light. I know that it allows for data context binding of a particular view to a static view model instance in the locator class.

But why do we need a separate locator class with all view model instances? What are the pros to it? What else is the locator used besides instantiating view models and data context purposes? 
For example, you can instantiate the view model in the code behind and set it as the data context of the view.

Comment: Dependency Injection is also managed by the locator

Answer (score 0):

I use a view model locator because I like to write my views as "view first" as opposed to "view model first" that a lot of people like to do. I think "view first" makes a lot more sense. Not only that, but it allows your VMs to be new'ed up automatically via DI assuming you've set everything up correctly. That way you don't have to new them up manually and set DataContexts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons for using the ViewModelLocator.

**Design time data**

Having the ViewModel wired up in the XAML (as opposed to the code-behind) means you have an active ViewModel when using the designer. You don't get that if you wire it up in the code-behind. That means you don't see any properties from the ViewModel while designing the page, don't get auto-complete for XAML bindings, etc.

**Dependency Injection**

With the ViewModelLocator you can easily make use of the power of dependency injection. You don't need to manually construct your ViewModels, they get created automatically with the proper dependencies (services).

**Wiring up different implementations for services for design or testing**

Related to the item above, using a ViewModelLocator allows you to easily use different services for different purposes. For example, you might not want to use the "real" web service for design time data. You can do that in the code-behind as well but then you'd have to do it over and over.

**But most importantly**

MVVMLight is a modularized frame-work. You can use of the parts you like, and ignore the parts you don't like. So if you prefer wiring up the ViewModel in the code-behind (maybe you don't like DI and you don't care about design-time data), there's nothing stopping you from doing that.